# Aggregation of query in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, having, group

I have table, like:

| Id | Account | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | ad@ind | 07.11.2022 | 354 |
| 2. | ad@ind | 10.11.2022 | 586 |

I need to find record, where is maximum number of month and get amount in this date. How is it to do? Max(date) does'nt fit, i need number inside month.

I tried to do group by date and amount, i tried to do inner query, but it was'nt lucky.

Comment: This is going to look something like `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE date = (SELECT max(date) FROM yourtable)`.

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding the question, but you might be interested in combining `extract(month from date)` into JNevill's answer.

Comment: Oh. "Number inside month" "maximum number of month" That was lost in translation for me @EdmCoff. Good catch.

Comment: Sorry, what would be the month for `07.11.2022`? 7 or 11? What if one month is in 2022 and the other in 2023? What if there is data for two accounts?

Comment: Also note that tables have _rows_, not records.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a record for each month, then consider the following solution using window function `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT id, account, date, amount
FROM 
    (
        SELECT yt.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) ORDER BY date DESC) as rn
        FROM yourtable yt 
     )dt
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This `ROW_NUMBER()` window function feature is generating a row_number, starting at 1, for each row that shares the same month and year, ordering by the `date` column descending. The record that gets `rn` of `1` is the highest date for that month/year combination.

---

Using similar logic as I shared in the comment, which is likely slower since two table scans are needed:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable yt
WHERE date = 
    (
        SELECT max(date)
        FROM yourtable yt2
        WHERE
           EXTRACT(MONTH FROM yt.date) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM yt2.date
           AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM yt.date) = EXTRACT YEAR FROM yt2.date)
     )
```

Comment: Thank you, i fogot about window function. But your code is getting only one account....